# Atom Syntax Error Hightlighting

Tags: atom-editor

Can anyone list a definitive solution to getting syntax error highlighting to work in Atom?  I've tried on and off throughout the last year or so, trying pretty much all the suggested methods on SO to get it working (installing linters, omnisharp, etc) and have had zero success.  If packages are available, I'd like to have support for C++ and C#.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: if one of the suggested methods you found on SO didnt work you could write a comment below that answers to ask for clarification, but what do you expect here what you didnt find in any of the answers you mention?

Comment: Stack Overflow is meant to help finding solutions for problems in programming, not to recommend tools or books. Try the [Atom forum](https://discuss.atom.io) for this kind of stuff.

Comment: I will most certainly post in Atom forum, however, I've seen hundreds of posts on tools and books on SO with no complaints from others, so thought it was acceptable.  Why is this rule not enforced?

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in a terminal:

```
$ apm install linter linter-ui-default
```

The command above installs the base packages needed for to use a linter in Atom.

To use a linter for C/C++:

```
$ apm install linter-gcc
```

For C# support:

```
$ apm install omnisharp-atom
```

Just go to https://atomlinter.github.io/ to see all the available linters for Atom.